# Change minimum restriction of a type within a complex type

Tags: xsd

I have a complex type called SafetyTiming and it has 2 elements value and margin. Both value and margin are based on a simpletype called Timing.

```
  <xs:simpleType name="Timing">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:unsignedInt">
      <xs:minInclusive value="0" />
      <xs:maxInclusive value="999" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:complexType name="SafetyTiming">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Value" type="Timing" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
      <xs:element name="Margin" type="Timing" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:element name="SafetyTimings">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:all>
        <xs:element name="A" type="SafetyTiming" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="B" type="SafetyTiming" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="C" type="SafetyTiming" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="D" type="SafetyTiming" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
      </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

This was fine until I found out that elements A and B need to have a minimum of 0 for simpletype "value" and, C and D a minimum of 1.

How can I elegantly solve this?

---

I tried the following but I think it looks rather messy and I wonder if there is a better solution.

```
  <!--Safety timing type containing the timing value (minimum 0) and the value margin-->
  <xs:complexType name="SafetyTiming_min0">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Value" type="Timing" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
      <xs:element name="Margin" type="Timing" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <!--Safety timing type containing the timing value (minimum 1) and the value margin-->
  <xs:complexType name="SafetyTiming_min1">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Value" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="Timing">
            <xs:minInclusive value="1" />
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Margin" type="Timing" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can derive a restricted type from `Timing`:

```
<xs:simpleType name="CDTiming">
    <xs:restriction base="Timing">
        <xs:minInclusive value="1" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

It's simpler to just create a new type for `C` and `D` which has the restricted `Value`:

```
<xs:complexType name="CDSafetyTiming">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Value" type="CDTiming" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="Margin" type="Timing" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

You don't need to change anything for `A` and `B` since the original type already has a minimum of `0`.

If you can change your original XSD, you can use the new type in the definition of your elements:

```
<xs:element name="SafetyTimings">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element name="A" type="SafetyTiming" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xs:element name="B" type="SafetyTiming" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xs:element name="C" type="CDSafetyTiming" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xs:element name="D" type="CDSafetyTiming" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: Yes, that is another way of doing it. I had just hoped there would be a way without creating another Timing or SafetyTiming object. Something like adding the new restrictions to xs:elements C and D directly.